# How to uninstall "qpid" in centos6.3

Tags: centos, qpid

I am unable to uninstall qpid from my centos VM. 
I have tried following::

-sudo yum erase qpid-cpp-server
-sudo yum remove qpid-cpp-server

But Its not getting uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

The dash before 'sudo' may be preventing the command from being recognized.

Try:

```
sudo yum remove qpid-cpp-server qpid-tools
```

Comment: Erik I have used below commands and it worked :
sudo yum remove qpid-tools
sudo yum remove qpid-cpp-server 
Thank you

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I could help. Keep in mind though for the future; stackoverflow is for programming questions, so questions of this nature should be posted on superuser.com. :)